# How to convert a NOT IN query into a JOIN query

Tags: mysql, join, notin

I have this following query that needs to be optimized

```sql
Select
    1 As status,
    e.entity_id,
    e.attribute_set_id,
    e.type_id,
    e.created_at,
    e.updated_at,
    e.sku,
    e.name,
    e.short_description,
    e.image,
    e.small_image,
    e.thumbnail,
    e.url_key,
    e.free,
    e.number_of_downloads,
    e.sentence1,
    e.url_path
From
    catalog_product_flat_1 As e
    Inner Join catalog_category_product_index_store1 As cat_index
        On cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id And
            cat_index.store_id = 1 And
            cat_index.visibility In (3, 2, 4) And
            cat_index.category_id = '2'
Where
    e.entity_id Not In (13863, 14096, 13856, 13924, 15875, 15869, 13788, 15977, 15873, 17141, 22214, 16900, 14485,
    15628, 15656, 14220, 14259, 14284, 13875, 13216, 14168, 13892, 16540, 19389, 17286, 16591, 30178, 31517, 31734,
    31621, 2487, 2486, 2485, 2484, 2483, 2482, 2481, 2480, 2479, 2478, 2477, 2475, 2474, 2473, 13402, 13427, 13694,
    13774, 13804, 13837, 13849, 13864, 30299, 30300) And
    e.free = 1
Order By
    e.number_of_downloads Desc;
```

Here The ids passed in NOT IN() are the "product_id" column values from a table named "mcsdownloads"

So my goal here is to replace NOT IN with a JOIN operation on table "mcsdownloads".

please help !

Comment: Please read: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ... IS NULL`:

```
SELECT  ...
    From  catalog_product_flat_1 As e
    Inner Join  catalog_category_product_index_store1 As cat_index
            ON cat_index.product_id = e.entity_id
    LEFT JOIN  mcsdownloads AS m  ON m.entity_id = e.entity_id
    WHERE  cat_index.store_id = 1
      And  cat_index.visibility In (3, 2, 4)
      And  cat_index.category_id = '2'
      AND  e.free = 1
      AND  m.entity_id IS NULL
```

(Note:  I moved the filtering criteria from `ON` to `WHERE`.  `ON` is used for saying how tables relate; `WHERE` is for filtering.)

Indexes needed:

```
cat_index:  INDEX(store_id, category_id, visibility, product_id)
e:  INDEX(free, number_of_downloads)
m:  INDEX(entity_id)
```

Comment: Amazing solution, it worked perfectly, didn't know we could use join like this, thanks a lot for saving my day!

Comment: So the purpose of my question here was to optimize query to reduce its execution speed as I thought JOIN would be taking lesser time as compare to NOT IN but from my results it turned out  NOT IN was actually faster than JOIN operation.

Just thought to post this as it may help someone in future.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to perform a join instead of not in, but you can arrange your code in the following way so that it works correctly without manually writing down all the `product_id` from the `mcsdownloads` table

```
SELECT 
   1 AS status, e.entity_id, e.attribute_set_id, 
   e.type_id, e.created_at, e.updated_at, e.sku, 
   e.name, e.short_description, e.image, e.small_image, 
   e.thumbnail, e.url_key, e.free, e.number_of_downloads, 
   e.sentence1, e.url_path 
FROM catalog_product_flat_1 AS e 
INNER JOIN catalog_category_product_index_store1 AS cat_index ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id 
  AND cat_index.store_id=1 
  AND cat_index.visibility IN (3,2,4) 
  AND cat_index.category_id='2' 
WHERE (e.entity_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM mcsdownloads)) 
  AND (e.free = 1) 
ORDER BY e.number_of_downloads DESC;
```

This is the significant part that I changed

```
e.entity_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM mcsdownloads)
```

Comment: Wrong.  It's the purpose of `LEFT`.

Comment: I really liked your answer and your way of thinking! Thanks!